# Split the records in text file

Tags: vb.net, console

I am working on vb.net application. In which I have multiple text files and need to split the records based on some identifier(repeated word) in file.
Could you please help me out as I am new to vb.net and don't know how to do this. 
So far I have coded

```
If (Directory.Exists(filePath)) Then
            'search file in the input path by their search pattern
            For Each File As String In Directory.GetFiles(filePath, "*.txt", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly)

                Console.WriteLine("Reading the current file " + Path.GetFileName(File))
                Using sr As StreamReader = New StreamReader(File)
                    Dim Currentline As String
                    Dim Identifier As String
                    Dim statementDate As String
                    Dim currenttext As String

                    'getting the unique identifier from the files and removing the white spaces
                    Identifier = sr.ReadLine.Substring(69, 8)
                    'checks until the EOF
                    While Not sr.EndOfStream

                        currenttext = sr.ReadLine()
                        'loop through until identified not repeated
                        Do Until currenttext.Contains(Identifier)

                            Currentline = sr.ReadLine()
                            Console.WriteLine(Currentline)


                        Loop
                        Console.WriteLine("=========================== Records Ends")

                    End While
                End Using
```

Also, Here is the screen shot of text file which needs to split.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you....

```
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Text

Sub Main()
    If (Directory.Exists(filePath)) Then
        For Each File As String In Directory.GetFiles(filePath, "*.txt", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly)
            Dim Record As New StringBuilder
            Dim Identifier As String = String.Empty

            Debug.Print("Reading the current file {0}", Path.GetFileName(File))
            Using sr As StreamReader = New StreamReader(File)
                While Not sr.EndOfStream
                    Dim ThisLine As String = sr.ReadLine.Trim

                    Select Case True
                        Case ThisLine.Length = 0
                            ' Skip blank lines
                        Case Identifier.Length = 0
                            ' We need to set the Identifier
                            Identifier = ThisLine
                        Case ThisLine = Identifier
                            ' We have the whole record
                            ProcessRecord(Record.ToString.Trim)

                            ' Reset for next record
                            Record.Clear()
                        Case Else
                            ' Add this line to the current record
                            Record.AppendLine(ThisLine)
                    End Select
                End While

                ' Process last record in file
                ProcessRecord(Record.ToString.Trim)
            End Using

            Debug.Print("=========================== File Ends")
        Next
    End If
End Sub

Sub ProcessRecord(Record As String)
    If Record.Length > 0 Then
        Debug.Print(Record)
        Debug.Print("=========================== Record Ends")
    End If
End Sub
```

*Original answer below*

```
If (Directory.Exists(filePath)) Then
    For Each File As String In Directory.GetFiles(filePath, "*.txt", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly)
        Dim AllLines() As String = IO.File.ReadAllLines(File)
        Dim Identifier As String = AllLines.First
        Dim Records() As String = Split(Join(AllLines, Environment.NewLine), Identifier)

        For Each Rec As String In Records
            Debug.Print(Rec)
            Debug.Print("=========================== Record Ends")
        Next
    Next

    Debug.Print("=========================== File Ends")
End If
```

Comment: I dont't want to use ReadAllLines. Beacuse it loads files in memory and could be memory issue. Is this possible with streamreader

Comment: @VirenderThakur I've revised my answer.

Answer (score 0):

In this example I made multiple text files. I hope to be helpful.

p.s. change   `Identifier = Mid(sr.ReadLine, 1, 5)` in  `Identifier = Mid(sr.ReadLine, 69, 8)`

Bye

```
 If (Directory.Exists(filePath)) Then

        Try
            'search file in the input path by their search pattern
            For Each File As String In Directory.GetFiles(filePath, "*.txt", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly)

                Console.WriteLine("Reading the current file " + Path.GetFileName(File))
                Using sr As StreamReader = New StreamReader(File)
                    Dim Currentline As String = ""
                    Dim Identifier As String = ""
                    Dim currenttext As String = ""
                    Dim Prog As Integer = 0
                    Dim flg As Boolean = True

                    While Not sr.EndOfStream

                        'getting the unique identifier from the files and removing the white spaces
                        Identifier = Mid(sr.ReadLine, 1, 5)

                        Do While Not sr.EndOfStream

                            Do While flg = True
                                Currentline = sr.ReadLine()
                                If Identifier = Currentline.Trim Then
                                    Exit Do
                                ElseIf sr.EndOfStream Then
                                    currenttext = currenttext + Currentline + vbCrLf
                                    Exit Do
                                End If
                                currenttext = currenttext + Currentline + vbCrLf
                            Loop

                            currenttext = currenttext + "=========================== Records Ends"

                            Prog += 1
                            Dim objWriter As New System.IO.StreamWriter(filePath + "\" + Path.GetFileName(File) + "_" + Prog.ToString + ".txt")
                            objWriter.WriteLine(currenttext)
                            objWriter.Close()
                            currenttext = ""
                        Loop

                    End While

                End Using

            Next

            MessageBox.Show("end")

        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
        End Try

    End If
```